# Why we still have beta references in VS2015 RTM [ASP.NET 5.0]

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Why we still have beta references in VS2015 RTM [ASP.NET 5.0]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/07/20/announcing-asp-net-4-6-and-asp-net-5-beta-5-in-visual-studio-2015-release.aspx) on the release.  It mentions beta 5 being included with Visual Studio 2015 (posted on the release day 7/20); seems like ASP.NET 5 final release is not ready for prime time.